# flutter_launcher_icons not working Unhandled exception: FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)

Tags: flutter-dependencies

I want to change my app icon in flutter using flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2 
It shows me errors while I'm running Command `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` 
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSZ5l.png)

I tried many times but no new results

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I just had the same problem and solved doing this in `android/app/build.gradle`.

Changed:

```
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

To:

```
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 30
```

[Source](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/88)

[Edit]
After that, I could not run on emulator, so I changed back the gradle file (without running flutter_launcher_icon again). Now I have the app running and the icons are right.

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot!

Comment: the minSdkVersion version can be set to 19 also. It will work

Comment: You can undo the changes too post generation of the app icons

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, but this did: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/324#issuecomment-1005736502

Comment: It did work. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to this [answer](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/324#issuecomment-1057617130), I was able to fix the issue!

Answer (score 1):

If the solution proposed by @Iagows doesn't work for you, have a look at this:
[flutter_launcher_icons-issues](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/324#issuecomment-1005736502)

Answer (score 1):

Inside file: ~/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.9.2/lib/android.dart

Replace Line:

```
 final String minSdk = line.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\d]'), '');
 To this:
 final String minSdk = "21"; // line.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\d]'), '');
```

Save the file and then run:

```
    flutter pub get
    flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Source : https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/324

Comment: this should be the answer, it goes directly to source of the problem and fix it without interfering with our build gradle

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the package version in `pubspec.yaml` and that solved the problem for me.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is explained in the readme of the plugin, section "Dependency incompatible". It says

```
Because flutter_launcher_icons >=0.9.0 depends on args 2.0.0 and flutter_native_splash 1.2.0 depends on args ^2.1.1, flutter_launcher_icons >=0.9.0 is incompatible with flutter_native_splash 1.2.0.
And because no versions of flutter_native_splash match >1.2.0 <2.0.0, flutter_launcher_icons >=0.9.0 is incompatible with flutter_native_splash ^1.2.0.
So, because enstack depends on both flutter_native_splash ^1.2.0 and flutter_launcher_icons ^0.9.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed
```

The solution is given in as cryptic a manner as the description above, but the simple hack given by @deffo worked for me.
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/324#issuecomment-1013611137

What you do is that you skip the version solving done when the plugin reads `build.gradle` and you force `minSdkVersion` to be whatever version you prefer.

It's a hack but since you generate automatically the app icons only once and for all, who cares? :-)

BTW, the following solution seems cleaner but I didn't test it: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/262#issuecomment-877653847